# CAn't connect to Oracle with Spring Boot and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I have a working Spring Boot app (1.2) that uses Postgres. Today I am trying to switch it to Oracle, but when I try to connect I get an exception that says:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

And below that,

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

So of course that looks like bad credentials, but I know they are good, and they are working in Oracle SQL Developer just fine. I'm baffled. Here are my properties file entries:

```
# Properties for Hibernate and Oracle
spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//earth-db-11:5121/stardev
spring.datasource.username=ops$abcdefg
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

The only idea I have is that there is a $ in the user name, and I have tried escaping it and putting double quotes around it.

Any ideas?

Thanks...

UPDATE:

Many thanks to BonanzaOne, I did have the port number wrong. Correcting that results in a new error:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

I looked it up of course, but I don't follow what its telling me:

```
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Cause: The listener received a request to establish a connection to a database
or other service. The connect descriptor received by the listener specified a
service name for a service (usually a database service) that either has not    yet
dynamically registered with the listener or has not been statically configured
for the listener. This may be a temporary condition such as after the listener
has started, but before the database instance has registered with the listener.
```

Still, SQL Explorer connects fine.

Comment: in favor of @BonanzaOne's answer, can you connect to Oracle with SQL Developer using the exact same credentials/connection url?

Comment: Oops, so stardev is an SID, not a service name. Just gotta figure out how to use the SID instead...

Comment: Got it! I had to change the / to a : AND remove the // before the host name. Thanks folks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That exception means that the Oracle listener is not up, or you are trying to connect to a listener that don't exist/not accessible.

My guess is that you trying the wrong port "5121". Oracle default port is **1521**.

Can you try with that and see what happens?

---

From the [FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC#Thin_driver) there are basically two ways of composing your JDBC string URL:

> **Old syntax**
>
> jdbc:oracle:thin:@[HOST][:PORT]:SID
>
> **New syntax**
>
> jdbc:oracle:thin:@//[HOST][:PORT]/SERVICE

My guess is that you are using the wrong syntax-SID/Service name combination, in other words, you are using the new syntax that requires the SERVICE name, but you are using the SID name to do it.

Try this: **jdbc:oracle:thin:@earth-db-11:1521:stardev**

Or maybe find out the Service name and apply it to the new syntax that you are using, instead of the SID name.

Comment: Ug, apparently I have been working too many hours. I did indeed have the port wrong as you said, thanks. Sadly, that only took me to a new error, I'll update the question. Still, SQL Explorer connects just fine, and with the same credentials in my properties file. Thanks very much!

Comment: Happy to hear you solved it! don't worry that is part of the fun ^^

Comment: this saved my day